# How do I add a timestamp to my query results?

Tags: sql, ssms

I want to add a column to my query results that repeats the current timestamp for all records returned.  This would effectively be a column that tells you when the query was executed.

Tried using With, Union, and Join...but it doesn't seem like there's a way to "print" data into sql results that are not already contained in the database.

```
Select * from myTable
Union
select current_timestamp
```

print (select current_timestamp)

The results would be all of the contents of the table with an extra column that has the current_timestamp for all records returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want the current_timestamp on each row resulting form select  You should only add  the col

```
Select *, current_timestamp  
from myTable
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
Select * from myTable
Union
select current_timestamp as timeStamp
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the TIMESTAMP in select clause like below -

```
Select *,current_timestamp from myTable
```